# R: login javascript form

Tags: javascript, r, authentication

I'm actual trying to log this site (http://bit.do) for scraping protected data.

I tried this approach founded in a previous question but it doesn't work.

```
library(rvest)
url       <-"http://bit.do/#login/admin"
pgsession <-html_session(url)

pgform    <-html_form(pgsession)[[2]]
filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
                  "username" = "username", 
                  "password" = "password")

submit_form(pgsession,filled_form)
```

but when I tried to head(pgform) i got this:
    $name
    [1] ""
    $method
    [1] "GET"
    $url
    NULL
    $enctype
    [1] "form"
    $fields
     '': 
     '': 
     '': 
     '': 
     '': Sign-up

That is quite different from what I expected. Maybe It is due to the code? I don't know, this is the only reason I can give to me. But if it's due to a javascript (instead html) how can I do the job?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to obtain the information to build a cookie then use that cookie in other requests:

```
library(httr)

POST(
  url = "https://inauth.insite.com.br/mod_perl/login.pl", 
  body = list(
    user_username = "YOUR_USERNAME", 
    user_password = "YOUR_PASSWORD", 
    lang = "en", 
    cookies = "no", 
    action = "chklogin", 
    app_id = "bit.do", 
    cookie_name = "InAuth-bitdo", 
    keep_logged_in_days = "5475"
  ),
  add_headers(
    `Referer` = "http://bit.d o/",
    `Origin` = "http://bit.d o",
    `X-Requested-With` = "XMLHttpRequest"
  )
) -> res

user_login_info <- content(res, as="parsed") 

GET(
  url = "https://bit.d o/admin",
  add_headers(`Referer` = "http://bit.d o/"), 
  set_cookies(`InAuth-bitdo` = user_login_info$auth_cookie_value)
) -> res
```

NOTE!!!! I had to put a space between the `d` and the `o` b/c the SO validator is brain dead.

They have a pay-for API which I suspect they expect you to use but they don't prohibit this scraping from what I can discern via a quick glance.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I'm newbie and I can't completely understand your code. Would you kindly please explain what you did here? I mean, how is it possible to authenticate through a third site? Why if I go to inauth.insite.com.br I can't fill form with all information you put in code but only with username and password? Also it doesn't return me any error, should I suppose everything is fine? Btw after that I tried to access to password protected data but it seems I'm not logged in

Comment: You should take some time to learn how basic networking & protocols work, then some more time to see how HTTP interactions work and then how web applications work and how to trace how they work. The best I can do is say that this site uses a third party for authentication (likely a central one for many of their apps), gets a session cookie from it which it then uses to authenticate you to the original site resources. It's how this app works. If nothing else, experiment with browser Developer Tools tutorials.

Comment: Absolutely I should do that and I will. Btw right now I need to solve this problem. Thank you for suggestion but I need a little bit more help. I tried to run your code (with my bit.do username and password, right?) and I get no errors but when I try to scrape data it seems I've no access to protected data as if I'm not logged in

    url <- 'http://bit.d o/admin/PROTECTED_DATA_PAGE'
    data_page <- read_html(url) 
    data <- html_nodes(data_page,'.CSS_SELECTOR')